# How to set dependency as runtime in SBT (to mimic runtime scope in Maven)?

Tags: sbt

I have a dependency in `runtime` scope in a Maven project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.docbook</groupId>
  <artifactId>docbook-xml</artifactId>
  <version>4.4</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

How can I express this in SBT?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use **Runtime** configuration for the dependency in `build.sbt` as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.docbook" % "docbook-xml" % "4.4" % Runtime
```

With this, classpath should be properly set - `show managedClasspath` for `compile` and `runtime` configurations to verify it:

```
[sbt-13-0-1]> help dependencyClasspath
The classpath consisting of internal and external, managed and unmanaged dependencies.
[sbt-13-0-1]> show managedClasspath
[info] List(Attributed(/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar))
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 1, 2014 12:10:57 AM
[sbt-13-0-1]> show runtime:managedClasspath
[info] List(Attributed(/Users/jacek/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar), Attributed(/Users/jacek/.ivy2/cache/org.docbook/docbook-xml/jars/docbook-xml-4.4.jar))
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 1, 2014 12:11:01 AM
```